# iOS core data + iCloud stores migration error

Tags: ios, core-data, save, icloud, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am developing a core data + iCloud based IOS app.
I took the sample code from apple and modified it
I am testing the scenario of migrating from fallback to iCloud store.
I simulated this scenario by disabling and enabling icloud drive in my phone for this app.
I am using iPhone 6 with IOS8.1
Xcode 6.3.2

I created only one record in fallback store. 
There is only one Entity (Doctors) and one attribute (name)

seedPSC - fallback store
_psc -cloudstore

When migrating i got the following error when saving the moc.
Please let me know what is causing this error
--------error------

```
2015-11-29 08:28:21.136 PlusData[187:3153] isicloudavailable 1
Using local storage: 1
2015-11-29 08:28:21.307 PlusData[187:3153] Added iCloud Store

2015-11-29 08:28:21.315 PlusData[187:3153] moving fallback to icloud
2015-11-29 08:28:21.335 PlusData[187:3153] addperson count 1 
2015-11-29 08:28:21.339 PlusData[187:3153] addperson name fff
2015-11-29 08:28:21.342 PlusData[187:3153]  moc sucess 0
2015-11-29 08:28:21.346 PlusData[187:3153]  moc save  localerror Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134020 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134020.)" UserInfo=0x17027acc0 {NSAffectedObjectsErrorKey=<NSManagedObject: 0x1702a27c0> (entity: Doctors; id: 0x170233900 <x-coredata://C1497C22-DCCC-4351-8EC6-93DE69D31F81/Doctors/tC0919182-F606-4D49-B2CF-72B064503CF02> ; data: {
    name = fff;
}), NSUnderlyingException=Store <NSSQLCore: 0x125e17320> (URL: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0188F553-8B2A-4B17-B55A-568D9DEA1DEE/Documents/PlusDaraStores/9A133545-F7AD-43C2-A5D6-AF4D1DACC5B3/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/mobile~3C7CB5E4-5917-4A3D-AB89-0FC8985D8CDE/iCloudStore/189A6953-A96B-4773-8E8D-C4BA1B0422E1/store/iCloudStore.sqlite) cannot hold instances of entity (<NSEntityDescription: 0x1703406e0>) name Doctors, managedObjectClassName NSManagedObject, renamingIdentifier Doctors, isAbstract 1, superentity name (null), properties {
    name = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x1701352c0>), name name, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Doctors, renamingIdentifier name, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null)";
}, subentities (null), userInfo {
}, versionHashModifier (null)}

    - (BOOL)seedStore:(NSPersistentStore *)store withPersistentStoreAtURL:(NSURL *)seedStoreURL error:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error {


    BOOL success = YES;
    NSError *localError = nil;

    NSManagedObjectModel *model = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *seedPSC = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];
    NSDictionary *seedStoreOptions = @{ NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption : [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] };
    NSPersistentStore *seedStore = [seedPSC addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                         configuration:nil
                                                                   URL:seedStoreURL
                                                               options:seedStoreOptions
                                                                 error:&localError];
    if (seedStore) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *seedMOC = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [seedMOC setPersistentStoreCoordinator:seedPSC];

        //fetch all the person objects, use a batched fetch request to control memory usage
        NSFetchRequest *fr = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Doctors"];
        NSUInteger batchSize = 5000;
        [fr setFetchBatchSize:batchSize];

        NSArray *people = [seedMOC executeFetchRequest:fr error:&localError];
         NSLog(@"addperson count %ld ",people.count);

        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

        [moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:_psc];
        NSUInteger i = 1;
        for (Doctor *person in people) {
            NSLog(@"addperson name %@",person.name);

            [self addPerson:person toStore:store withContext:moc];
            if (0 == (i % batchSize)) {
                success = [moc save:&localError]; //seedstore
                if (success) {
                    /*
                     Reset the managed object context to free the memory for the inserted objects
                     The faulting array used for the fetch request will automatically free objects
                     with each batch, but inserted objects remain in the managed object context for
                     the lifecycle of the context
                     */
                    [moc reset];
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Error saving during seed: %@", localError);
                    break;
                }
            }

            i++;
        }

        //one last save
        if ([moc hasChanges]) {
            NSLog(@" moc save  called");
            success = [moc save:&localError];
            NSLog(@" moc sucess %ld",success);
            NSLog(@" moc save  localerror %@",localError);
            [moc reset];
        }
    } else {
        success = NO;
        NSLog(@"Error adding seed store: %@", localError);
    }

    if (NO == success) {
        if (localError  && (error != NULL)) {
            *error = localError;
        }
    }

    return success;
}

- (void)addPerson:(Doctor *)person toStore:(NSPersistentStore *)store withContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc {
    //save is done in called function

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [person entity];
    Doctor *newPerson = [[Doctor alloc] initWithEntity:entity
                           insertIntoManagedObjectContext:moc];

    newPerson.name = person.name;


    [moc assignObject:newPerson toPersistentStore:store];


}
```